# Using tKinter askdirectory() with glob

Tags: python, tkinter, glob

I have a script that uses tKinter to create window and allow users to browse and select a directory.  I then use glob to grab the files in the directory... but this gives me some weird paths, such as:

//file-server/selected_folder\\file01.xlsx

When I go to use that path, nothing is returned.  I'm in a Windows environment selecting a folder from the network, if that makes any difference.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import glob

def browse(*args):
    directory.set(filedialog.askdirectory())
    return

def parse(*args):
    all_files = None
    all_files = glob.glob( directory.get() + "/*.nessus")

def main_menu():    
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Parse Files")
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    global directory
    directory = StringVar()

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Directory of Files: ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
    dir_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30, textvariable=directory)
    dir_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command=browse).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Parse", command=parse).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    dir_entry.focus()
    root.bind('<Return>', parse)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()
```

Comment: You should probably normalize the filenames, it looks like an UNC path with slashes in the wrong direction. Tcl/Tk usually does not care too much, as it has its own virtual filesystem layer and would fix it, but python might care.

Comment: I tried using re.sub('\/', '//', directory.get()) but received errors.  Is there another method I could use to normalize the filenames?

Comment: how about the functions in `os.path`, like `os.path.normpath()`.

Comment: That's what I needed.  Post as an answer and I'll select it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you get seems denormalized in some way. It is a little strange that you have a filename as a result from `askdirectory`, which might be the result of some kind of shell extension (e.g. open ZIP files or something like that), the normal `tk_chooseDirectory` which is used by `tkinters` `askdirectory` wouldn't do that on its own.

So you should normalize the path again, to remove those two extra `\` before the filename.

The tool in python to do this is `os.path.normpath()`.

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.path.normpath('//file-server/selected_folder\\file01.xlsx'))
\\file-server\selected_folder\file01.xlsx
```